# NGINX + Apache [загрузка 8 ядер под 100%]

Tags: apache, nginx, hosts, virtual

NGINX + Apache [загрузка 8 ядер под 100%]

Comment: Ели убираю код:    location ~ /    {        client_max_body_size 10m;        client_body_buffer_size 16k;        proxy_buffer_size  8k;        proxy_buffers   8 8k;        access_log off;        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;        proxy_set_header Host $host;        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;        proxy_connect_timeout 120;        proxy_send_timeout    120;        proxy_read_timeout    180;    }То при удерживании F5, вылезает ошибка 503 (то, что нужно), но сайт долго грузится и картинки не прогружаются

Comment: вам тело вопроса зачем дано ? чтобы комментарии на пол экрана делать ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если посмотришь историю, то увидишь, что я удалил уже вопрос.